# How should a backdoor be delivered?

Tags: backdoor

I am wondering about the ways a backdoor could be delivered to someone and the advantages and disadvantages of the various ways.

As a backdoor, I mean a script or payload that may be able to get a reverse tcp/http connection to a server in a way to obtain informations from the victim. This script could be sent as an embedded file, through any kind of direct access of the computer's victim, or even click-jacking.

What I would like to know is: Is it better to deliver only a piece of the whole backdoor(the one with some basic functions like: the connection one, download of files, upload, etc). Then, after obtaining access to the computer send other files (.exe) with functions like keylogger, packet filter, password dump, etc? Or would it be better to send only one file (.exe) containing all the functions, the whole backdoor?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of both methods, when should I use each one?

Comment: Can you clarify your question some? What type of backdoor are you referring to? Vendor backdoors, law-enforcement backdoors, backdoors added by an attacker?

Comment: A backdoor is an extremely broad term that describes a way of having covert access to a system. How it's implemented depends on the system you're targeting, your level of privilege on it (root vs normal user) and how hidden you want it to be.

Answer (score 3):

There are many different types of backdoors which an attacker could setup on a system. These include

- Adding an account with administrative privileges.
- Adding a daemon to a system which listens for connections, possibly on a high port, and provides remote shell access.
- It could be software running on the system which calls out to a remote site for commands it needs to run.
- Modification to existing system configurations or applications such that commands can be remotely executed.
- Modification or addition of code to things, possibly a website, which would then allow remote code to be executed. PHP shells would be an example of this.
- Modifications to documents that when parsed or opened allow for code execution or remote requests.
- Etc... Possibly hundreds of other examples.

As you can tell not all of these would need to have a script involved and also most of these could be set up via the execution of a script or program. Your question is a bit broad as currently written (at the time I'm reading it) but hopefully this helps answer it.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't about backdoors, but about the delivery method of infections in general.

Yes, you can have either a staged infection where updates or more functionality is added in stages.

The advantage of this is that it is possible to evade IDS and packet inspection because you can split up or hide the malicious code.

The disadvantage is that you need a reliable and longer-term connection in order to receive the updates. Also, repeated connections from/to a victim to the update source might be seen as suspicious.